# How to make S3 generic plotting function in R?

Tags: r, function

So I have been trying to make an S3 generic plotting function in R... I have read several blogs and examples explaining S3 functions... but I'm still having trouble figuring this out. In my package I have a function that creates a matrix. Then, I also have another function that takes the created matrix as an argument and then plots this matrix as a heat-map. I am trying to turn this second function (i.e., plotting heat-map) into an S3 generic function. The example below will hopefully explain what I mean.

To begin I have a function to create a matrix:

```
#' myMatrix
#'
#' @description Creates Matrix
#'
#' @param rows No of rows
#' @param cols No of cols
#'
#' @importFrom stats "runif"
#'
#' @export

myMatrix <- function(rows = 10, cols = 10){

n <- rows   # no or rows
p <- cols    # no of cols

# Create matrix of values
myMat <- matrix(runif(n*p, 0, 1), nrow=n)               # Create matrix
colnames(myMat) <- paste0("x", 1:p)                     # Name columns
rownames(myMat) <- paste0("x", 1:p)                     # Name rows
return(myMat)
}
```

I would then store the result of the matrix like so:

```
mat <- myMatrix(10,10)
```

Then, in a separate script, I was trying to create the S3 generic plotting function, like so:

```
#' heatMapTEST
#'
#' @description Plots plot
#'
#' @param myMat Given Matrix
#'
#' @importFrom ggplot2 "ggplot"
#'
#' @export

heatMapTEST <- function(myMat){
  UseMethod('plot')}

#' @export
plot.heatMapTEST <- function(myMat){

  df <- reshape2::melt(myMat, c("x", "y"), value.name = "z")
  head(df)
  ggplot(data=df,aes(x=x,y=y,fill=z))+
    geom_tile()
}
```

And then (I guess) I would call it like so:

```
plot(heatMapTEST(mat))
```

But this throws back an error saying:

> Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) :    error in evaluating the
> argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'plot': no applicable
> method for 'plot' applied to an object of class "c('matrix', 'array',
> 'double', 'numeric')"

I'm very new to writing S3 methods, so really I have no idea if I'm even partially correct in how im doing this... any suggestions as to how I would create a generic S3 to allow me to use the `heatMapTEST` function with the generic `plot` function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The S3 methods work when you add classes to your objects. If you want your matrix to have a special plotting method, then you just need to add a class to it. Observe

```
myMatrix <- function(rows = 10, cols = 10){
  
  n <- rows   # no or rows
  p <- cols    # no of cols
  
  # Create matrix of values
  myMat <- matrix(runif(n*p, 0, 1), nrow=n)               # Create matrix
  colnames(myMat) <- paste0("x", 1:p)                     # Name columns
  rownames(myMat) <- paste0("x", 1:p)                     # Name rows
  class(myMat) <- c("heatMapTEST", class(myMat))
  return(myMat)
}
class(myMatrix(10, 10))
# [1] "heatMapTEST" "matrix"      "array"
```

So this function now has the class "heatMapTEST" but it will also behave like a matrix is no special methods for that class exist. When you call `plot()`, it will look to match the first class it can. You can see all the existing generic plot methods with `methods(plot)`. You can create your own just as you did above

```
plot.heatMapTEST <- function(myMat){
  df <- reshape2::melt(myMat, c("x", "y"), value.name = "z")
  head(df)
  ggplot(data=df,aes(x=x,y=y,fill=z))+
    geom_tile()
}
```

and you would just call `plot()` on the object returned from `myMatrix` to get your plot

```
plot(myMatrix(10,10))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that clears things up a lot. However, follow up question. In my package I have multiple functions that take the matrix as an argument and plots it in different ways. For example, if, say, I had another plotting function called `scatterPlotTEST`.. how would I incorporate that as well as `heatMapTEST`?

Comment: I just used an `if` statement to choose which plot to display. Thanks for your help